# Xilinx fuse compilation of vhdl code fails on debian because of glibc memory corruption

Tags: linux, gcc, vhdl, xilinx

I'm trying to compile a vhdl file using xilinx's fuse (part of ISE) using a library I got from my university - `pgm_pkg.vhd`. The library is used to read the *.pgm image format into vhdl simulator. It works ok when simulated in Modelsim at windows, but unfortunately while compiling on debian using fuse it produces the following error:
`*** glibc detected *** /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE/bin/lin64/unwrapped/fuse: malloc(): memory corruption (fast): 0x00000000019c7780 ***`

Using Modelsim (which is soo slow in student version) at virtual machine running windows (which makes it even slower) is something I would like to avoid at any cost. 
I've narrowed the problem down to the function `read_pgm_file()` which iterates over the *.pgm file and provides the subsequent pixels of the image.

I've read that this kind of error is raised by gcc often many lines before the compilation crushes, but even that isn't helpful as fuse is a closed-source application. I've tried using different *.pgm pictures, I've also tried to compile it using verbose mode (I didn't find there anything helpful) and with the compilation multithreading off - still the same error occurs.

1) How do I handle such an error? Are there any tools for debugging during compilation?
2) What's wrong with the library? I can't see anything that could cause problems, especially that the same library works on windows very well.

The vhdl test file:
        library IEEE;
        use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
        use IEEE.std_logic_arith.all;
        use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;

```
    USE work.pgm_pkg.ALL; -- read and write pgm format files package (max 512x512)

    entity test_raw_tb is
        GENERIC (
                    ifile : STRING := "pepper.ascii.pgm"
        );
    end test_raw_tb;

    architecture behavioral of test_raw_tb is
        constant infile : pgm_record_type := read_pgm_file(ifile);
    begin   -- architecture

    end behavioral;
```

The pgm_pkg.vhd library:

```
PACKAGE pgm_pkg IS

    constant max : NATURAL := 640;
    constant pgm_row_size : integer :=18;

  TYPE pixel_array_type IS ARRAY(0 TO max-1, 0 TO max - 1) OF integer;

  TYPE pgm_record_type IS RECORD
    magic_number : STRING(1 TO 2);
    width        : NATURAL;
    height       : NATURAL;
    max_val      : NATURAL;
    pixel        : pixel_array_type;
  END RECORD;

  IMPURE FUNCTION read_pgm_file(filename : IN STRING) 
  RETURN pgm_record_type;

  IMPURE FUNCTION write_pgm_file(filename : IN STRING; pgm : pgm_record_type) 
  RETURN BOOLEAN;

  IMPURE FUNCTION write_pgm_comment_file(filename : IN STRING; pgm : pgm_record_type) 
  RETURN BOOLEAN;

END pgm_pkg;
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
library std;
use std.textio.all;

PACKAGE BODY pgm_pkg IS

   IMPURE FUNCTION read_pgm_file(filename : IN STRING) 
    RETURN pgm_record_type IS
    FILE     filehandle   : TEXT open read_mode is filename;
    VARIABLE inline       : LINE;
    VARIABLE inline_copy  : LINE;
    VARIABLE char         : CHARACTER;
    VARIABLE good         : BOOLEAN;
    VARIABLE number       : integer;
    VARIABLE header_index : NATURAL;
    VARIABLE magic_number : STRING(1 TO 2);
    VARIABLE got_magic_number : BOOLEAN := FALSE;
    VARIABLE width        : NATURAL;
    VARIABLE height       : NATURAL;
    VARIABLE max_val      : NATURAL;
    VARIABLE got_header   : BOOLEAN;
    VARIABLE pi,pj        : NATURAL; -- pixel index
    VARIABLE pgm          : pgm_record_type;
  BEGIN
    got_magic_number := FALSE;
    got_header := FALSE;
    header_index := 0;
    pi := 0; -- pixel index
    pj := 0;
    WHILE (NOT(ENDFILE(filehandle))) LOOP
      READLINE(filehandle, inline);
      -- make a copy of inline string for later (note it's an access type)
      inline_copy := new STRING'(inline.ALL);
      READ(inline, char, good);
      -- move on to next line if it's a comment
      NEXT WHEN char = '#';
      -- special case for magic number
      IF (got_magic_number = FALSE) THEN
        ASSERT (char = 'P' OR char = 'p')
          REPORT "Error: Not PGM format file. Magic number should start with P."
          SEVERITY FAILURE;
        READ(inline, char, good);
        ASSERT (char = '2')
          REPORT "Error: Not ASCII PGM format file. Magic number should be P2."
          SEVERITY FAILURE;
        pgm.magic_number(1) := 'P';
        pgm.magic_number(2) := '2';
        got_magic_number := TRUE;
        -- strip off first two characters of inline_copy as they were magic_number
        READ(inline_copy, char, good);
        READ(inline_copy, char, good);
      END IF;
      IF (got_magic_number = TRUE) THEN 
        good := TRUE;
        WHILE (inline_copy'LENGTH /= 0 AND good = TRUE) LOOP
          READ(inline_copy, number, good);
          IF (good = TRUE) THEN
            IF (got_header = TRUE) THEN
              pgm.pixel(pi,pj) := number;
              pj := pj + 1;
              if pj=pgm.width then
                 pj:=0;
                 pi:=pi+1;
              end if;
            ELSE
              IF (header_index = 0) THEN -- it must be width
                pgm.width := number;
                header_index := 1; -- look for height next
                ELSIF (header_index = 1) THEN -- it must be height
                pgm.height := number;
                header_index := 2; -- look for max_val next
              ELSE -- it must be max_val
                pgm.max_val := number;
                got_header := TRUE;
              END IF; -- header_index
            END IF; -- got_header
          END IF; -- good
        END LOOP;
      END IF; -- got_magic_number = TRUE
    END LOOP; -- NOT ENDFILE
    ASSERT got_header
      REPORT "Error: Can't find header information - giving up."
      SEVERITY FAILURE;      
    RETURN pgm;
  END read_pgm_file;

-----------------------------------------------------------------------

  IMPURE FUNCTION write_pgm_comment_file(filename : IN STRING;
                          pgm : pgm_record_type) 
    RETURN BOOLEAN IS
    FILE     filehandle : TEXT open write_mode is filename;
    VARIABLE outline : LINE;
    VARIABLE pi,pj : NATURAL; -- pixel index
    VARIABLE k : NATURAL := 0;
    CONSTANT row_comment : STRING := "# row ";
  BEGIN

    WRITE(outline, pgm.magic_number);
    WRITELINE(filehandle, outline);
    WRITE(outline, pgm.width);
    WRITELINE(filehandle, outline);
    WRITE(outline, pgm.height);
    WRITELINE(filehandle, outline);
    WRITE(outline, pgm.max_val);
    WRITELINE(filehandle, outline);
    pi := 0;
    pj := 0;
    k := 0;

    wfile_i: 
    for pi in 0 to pgm.height-1 loop
        write(outline, string'("# row "));
        write(outline, pi, left, 5);
        writeline(filehandle, outline);
        wfile_j: 
        for pj in 0 to pgm.width-1 loop
            write(outline,pgm.pixel(pi,pj),right,4);
            if k < (pgm_row_size - 1) then
                k:=k+1;
            else
                writeline(filehandle,outline); 
                k:=0;
            end if;
        end loop wfile_j;
        k:=0;       
        writeline(filehandle,outline); 
    end loop wfile_i;

    RETURN TRUE;
end write_pgm_comment_file;

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

  IMPURE FUNCTION write_pgm_file(filename : IN STRING;
                          pgm : pgm_record_type) 
    RETURN BOOLEAN IS
    FILE     filehandle : TEXT open write_mode is filename;
    VARIABLE outline : LINE;
    VARIABLE pi,pj : NATURAL; -- pixel index
    VARIABLE k : NATURAL := 0;
  BEGIN

    WRITE(outline, pgm.magic_number);
    WRITELINE(filehandle, outline);
    WRITE(outline, pgm.width);
    WRITE(outline, ' ');
    WRITE(outline, pgm.height);
    WRITELINE(filehandle, outline);
    WRITE(outline, pgm.max_val);
    WRITELINE(filehandle, outline);
    pi := 0;
    pj := 0;
    k := 0;

       wfile_i: 
       for pi in 0 to pgm.height-1 loop
           wfile_j: 
           for pj in 0 to pgm.width-1 loop
               write(outline,pgm.pixel(pi,pj),right,4);
               if k < (pgm_row_size - 1) then
                   k:=k+1;
               else
                   writeline(filehandle,outline); 
                   k:=0;
               end if;
           end loop wfile_j;
           k:=0;
           writeline(filehandle,outline); 
       end loop wfile_i;

    RETURN TRUE;
    end write_pgm_file;

end pgm_pkg;
```

Compilation log:

```
Compilation of test_raw_tb.vhd...
Running: /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE/bin/lin64/unwrapped/fuse -v 2 -mt off -o test_raw_tb.exe -prj test_raw_tb.prj test_raw_tb 
ISim P.49d (signature 0xfbc00daa)
Turned off multi-threading for compilation
Determining compilation order of HDL files
--output trimmed--
Parsing VHDL file "pgm_pkg.vhd" into library work
Parsing VHDL file "test_raw_tb.vhd" into library work
Starting static elaboration
Executing test_raw_tb(behavioral)
*** glibc detected *** /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE/bin/lin64/unwrapped/fuse: malloc(): memory corruption (fast): 0x00000000019c7780 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x76d76)[0x7f11af7c4d76]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7a658)[0x7f11af7c8658]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_malloc+0x70)[0x7f11af7c9b90]
/opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE//lib/lin64/libstlport.so.5.1(_Znwm+0x1d)[0x7f11b2b7909d]
/opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE//lib/lin64/libPortability.so(_ZN15Port_MsgManData12createObjectEPKcS1_iS1_+0x33)[0x7f11b286a043]
/opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE/bin/lin64/unwrapped/fuse[0x5fe2ba]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0xf030)[0x7f11b0180030]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x1277fc)[0x7f11af8757fc]
/opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE//lib/lin64/libVrfc_Verific.so(_ZN7Verific5Array6RemoveEjj+0x3a)[0x7f11b3748906]
/opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE//lib/lin64/libVrfc_Verific.so(_ZN7Verific16VhdlSubprogramId24ElaboratePragmaProcedureEPKNS_5ArrayEPNS_12VhdlDataFlowE+0x145f)[0x7f11b3a2e295]
/opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE//lib/lin64/libVrfc_Verific.so(_ZN7Verific16VhdlSubprogramId19ElaborateSubprogramEPNS_5ArrayEPNS_14VhdlConstraintEPNS_12VhdlDataFlowEPNS_12VhdlTreeNodeEPNS_9VhdlIdDefE+0xf3)[0x7f11b3a2e8b1]
/opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE//lib/lin64/libVrfc_Verific.so(_ZN7Verific15VhdlIndexedName8EvaluateEPNS_14VhdlConstraintEPNS_12VhdlDataFlowEj+0x12b)[0x7f11b3a4cc81]
/opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE//lib/lin64/libVrfc_Verific.so(_ZN7Verific26VhdlProcedureCallStatement9ElaborateEPNS_12VhdlDataFlowEPNS_22VhdlBlockConfigurationE+0x3e)[0x7f11b3a85c7a]
/opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE//lib/lin64/libVrfc_Verific.so(_ZN7Verific15VhdlWhileScheme9ElaborateEPNS_9VhdlIdDefEPNS_5ArrayES4_PNS_22VhdlBlockConfigurationEPNS_12VhdlDataFlowE+0x2b3)[0x7f11b3a38867]
/opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE//lib/lin64/libVrfc_Verific.so(_ZN7Verific17VhdlLoopStatement9ElaborateEPNS_12VhdlDataFlowEPNS_22VhdlBlockConfigurationE+0xfe)[0x7f11b3a85da8]
/opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE//lib/lin64/libVrfc_Verific.so(_ZN7Verific15VhdlIfStatement13ElaborateCoreEPNS_12VhdlDataFlowE+0x24f)[0x7f11b3a88731]
/opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE//lib/lin64/libVrfc_Verific.so(_ZN7Verific15VhdlIfStatement9ElaborateEPNS_12VhdlDataFlowEPNS_22VhdlBlockConfigurationE+0x52)[0x7f11b3a88e8a]
/opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE//lib/lin64/libVrfc_Verific.so(_ZN7Verific15VhdlWhileScheme9ElaborateEPNS_9VhdlIdDefEPNS_5ArrayES4_PNS_22VhdlBlockConfigurationEPNS_12VhdlDataFlowE+0x2b3)[0x7f11b3a38867]
/opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE//lib/lin64/libVrfc_Verific.so(_ZN7Verific17VhdlLoopStatement9ElaborateEPNS_12VhdlDataFlowEPNS_22VhdlBlockConfigurationE+0xfe)[0x7f11b3a85da8]
/opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE//lib/lin64/libVrfc_Verific.so(_ZN7Verific18VhdlSubprogramBody19ElaborateSubprogramEPKNS_5ArrayEPNS_14VhdlConstraintEPNS_12VhdlDataFlowEPNS_12VhdlTreeNodeEjPNS_9VhdlIdDefE+0x1217)[0x7f11b3a10cdf]
/opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE//lib/lin64/libVrfc_Verific.so(_ZN7Verific16VhdlSubprogramId19ElaborateSubprogramEPNS_5ArrayEPNS_14VhdlConstraintEPNS_12VhdlDataFlowEPNS_12VhdlTreeNodeEPNS_9VhdlIdDefE+0x1aa)[0x7f11b3a2e968]
/opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE//lib/lin64/libVrfc_Verific.so(_ZN7Verific15VhdlIndexedName8EvaluateEPNS_14VhdlConstraintEPNS_12VhdlDataFlowEj+0x12b)[0x7f11b3a4cc81]
/opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE//lib/lin64/libVrfc_Verific.so(_ZN7Verific16VhdlConstantDecl9ElaborateEPNS_12VhdlDataFlowE+0x8b)[0x7f11b3a0d7f1]
/opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE//lib/lin64/libVrfc_Verific.so(_ZN7Verific20VhdlArchitectureBody15StaticElaborateEPNS_22VhdlBlockConfigurationE+0x9e)[0x7f11b3ac9c54]
/opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE//lib/lin64/libVrfc_Verific.so(_ZN7Verific14VhdlEntityDecl23StaticElaborateInternalEPKcPNS_5ArrayES4_PNS_22VhdlBlockConfigurationEPNS_9VhdlIdDefE+0x3ff)[0x7f11b3ac91d1]
/opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE//lib/lin64/libVrfc_Verific.so(_ZN7Verific14VhdlEntityDecl15StaticElaborateEPKcPNS_5ArrayES4_PNS_22VhdlBlockConfigurationEPNS_9VhdlIdDefE+0x157)[0x7f11b3ac7f35]
/opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE/bin/lin64/unwrapped/fuse(_ZN5ISIMC4Fuse15elaborateDesignEv+0x27a)[0x4550aa]
/opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE/bin/lin64/unwrapped/fuse(_ZN5ISIMC4Fuse3runEv+0x117)[0x46aaf7]
/opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE/bin/lin64/unwrapped/fuse(_ZN5ISIMC4Fuse4mainEiPPc+0x59)[0x46bcb9]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd)[0x7f11af76cead]
/opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE/bin/lin64/unwrapped/fuse(__gxx_personality_v0+0x209)[0x451c49]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-006c0000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 1977591                            /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE/bin/lin64/unwrapped/fuse
008c0000-008c7000 rw-p 002c0000 08:05 1977591                            /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE/bin/lin64/unwrapped/fuse
008c7000-008c8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
01602000-019cf000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f11a8000000-7f11a8021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f11a8021000-7f11ac000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f11aec42000-7f11aef92000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 1978523                    /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libxercesc.so
7f11aef92000-7f11af191000 ---p 00350000 08:05 1978523                    /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libxercesc.so
7f11af191000-7f11af1ce000 rw-p 0034f000 08:05 1978523                    /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libxercesc.so
7f11af1ce000-7f11af1cf000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f11af1cf000-7f11af22f000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 1978520                    /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libUtilC_MessageDispatcher.so
7f11af22f000-7f11af42f000 ---p 00060000 08:05 1978520                    /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libUtilC_MessageDispatcher.so
7f11af42f000-7f11af433000 rw-p 00060000 08:05 1978520                    /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libUtilC_MessageDispatcher.so
7f11af433000-7f11af449000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 1978531                    /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libboost_zlib-gcc41-mt-p-1_38.so.1.38.0
7f11af449000-7f11af548000 ---p 00016000 08:05 1978531                    /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libboost_zlib-gcc41-mt-p-1_38.so.1.38.0
7f11af548000-7f11af549000 rw-p 00015000 08:05 1978531                    /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libboost_zlib-gcc41-mt-p-1_38.so.1.38.0
7f11af549000-7f11af54d000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 786505                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1.3.0
7f11af54d000-7f11af74c000 ---p 00004000 08:05 786505                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1.3.0
7f11af74c000-7f11af74d000 r--p 00003000 08:05 786505                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1.3.0
7f11af74d000-7f11af74e000 rw-p 00004000 08:05 786505                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1.3.0
7f11af74e000-7f11af8ce000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 786451                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so
7f11af8ce000-7f11aface000 ---p 00180000 08:05 786451                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so
7f11aface000-7f11afad2000 r--p 00180000 08:05 786451                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so
7f11afad2000-7f11afad3000 rw-p 00184000 08:05 786451                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so
7f11afad3000-7f11afad8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f11afad8000-7f11afaed000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 786436                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f11afaed000-7f11afced000 ---p 00015000 08:05 786436                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f11afced000-7f11afcee000 rw-p 00015000 08:05 786436                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f11afcee000-7f11afd6f000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 786448                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.13.so
7f11afd6f000-7f11aff6e000 ---p 00081000 08:05 786448                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.13.so
7f11aff6e000-7f11aff6f000 r--p 00080000 08:05 786448                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.13.so
7f11aff6f000-7f11aff70000 rw-p 00081000 08:05 786448                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.13.so
7f11aff70000-7f11b0056000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 1983260                    /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libstdc++.so.6
7f11b0056000-7f11b0156000 ---p 000e6000 08:05 1983260                    /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libstdc++.so.6
7f11b0156000-7f11b0157000 r--p 000e6000 08:05 1983260                    /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libstdc++.so.6
7f11b0157000-7f11b015f000 rw-p 000e7000 08:05 1983260                    /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libstdc++.so.6
7f11b015f000-7f11b0171000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f11b0171000-7f11b0188000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 786441                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.13.so
7f11b0188000-7f11b0387000 ---p 00017000 08:05 786441                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.13.so
7f11b0387000-7f11b0388000 r--p 00016000 08:05 786441                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.13.so
7f11b0388000-7f11b0389000 rw-p 00017000 08:05 786441                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.13.so
7f11b0389000-7f11b038d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f11b038d000-7f11b038f000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 786444                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.13.so
7f11b038f000-7f11b058f000 ---p 00002000 08:05 786444                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.13.so
7f11b058f000-7f11b0590000 r--p 00002000 08:05 786444                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.13.so
7f11b0590000-7f11b0591000 rw-p 00003000 08:05 786444                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.13.so
7f11b0591000-7f11b05df000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 1978522                    /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libUtilities.so
7f11b05df000-7f11b07de000 ---p 0004e000 08:05 1978522                    /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libUtilities.so
7f11b07de000-7f11b07e1000 rw-p 0004d000 08:05 1978522                    /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libUtilities.so
7f11b07e1000-7f11b07f2000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 1978515                    /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libStaticFileParsers.so
7f11b07f2000-7f11b09f2000 ---p 00011000 08:05 1978515                    /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libStaticFileParsers.so
7f11b09f2000-7f11b09f3000 rw-p 00011000 08:05 1978515                    /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libStaticFileParsers.so
7f11b09f3000-7f11b0a02000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 1978526                    /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libboost_bzip2-gcc41-mt-p-1_38.so.1.38.0
7f11b0a02000-7f11b0b01000 ---p 0000f000 08:05 1978526                    /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libboost_bzip2-gcc41-mt-p-1_38.so.1.38.0
7f11b0b01000-7f11b0b03000 rw-p 0000e000 08:05 1978526                    /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libboost_bzip2-gcc41-mt-p-1_38.so.1.38.0
7f11b0b03000-7f11b0b04000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 1978009                    /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libCit_Core.so
7f11b0b04000-7f11b0d04000 ---p 00001000 08:05 1978009                    /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libCit_Core.so
7f11b0d04000-7f11b0d05000 rw-p 00001000 08:05 1978009                    /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libCit_Core.so
7f11b0d05000-7f11b0d8a000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 1978505                    /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libPersonalityModule.so
7f11b0d8a000-7f11b0f89000 ---p 00085000 08:05 1978505                    /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libPersonalityModule.so
7f11b0f89000-7f11b0f8e000 rw-p 00084000 08:05 1978505                    /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libPersonalityModule.so
7f11b0f8e000-7f11b0f9b000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 1978528                    /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libboost_iostreams-gcc41-mt-p-1_38.so.1.38.0
7f11b0f9b000-7f11b109a000 ---p 0000d000 08:05 1978528                    /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libboost_iostreams-gcc41-mt-p-1_38.so.1.38.0
7f11b109a000-7f11b109b000 rw-p 0000c000 08:05 1978528                    /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libboost_iostreams-gcc41-mt-p-1_38.so.1.38.0
7f11b109b000-7f11b1153000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 1978529                    /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libboost_regex-gcc41-mt-p-1_38.so.1.38.0
7f11b1153000-7f11b1252000 ---p 000b8000 08:05 1978529                    /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libboost_regex-gcc41-mt-p-1_38.so.1.38.0
7f11b1252000-7f11b1257000 rw-p 000b7000 08:05 1978529                    /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libboost_regex-gcc41-mt-p-1_38.so.1.38.0
7f11b1257000-7f11b1260000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 1978503                    /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libMiniZip.so
7f11b1260000-7f11b145f000 ---p 00009000 08:05 1978503                    /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libMiniZip.so
7f11b145f000-7f11b1460000 rw-p 00008000 08:05 1978503                    /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libMiniZip.so
7f11b1460000-7f11b1476000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 1978525                    /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libZlib.so
7f11b1476000-7f11b1675000 ---p 00016000 08:05 1978525                    /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libZlib.so
7f11b1675000-7f11b1676000 rw-p 00015000 08:05 1978525                    /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libZlib.so
7f11b1676000-7f11b1680000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 1978518                    /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libThread.so
7f11b1680000-7f11b187f000 ---p 0000a000 08:05 1978518                    /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libThread.so
7f11b187f000-7f11b1880000 rw-p 00009000 08:05 1978518                    /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libThread.so
7f11b1880000-7f11b1883000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f11b1883000-7f11b188b000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 1978507                    /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libPort_Std.so
7f11b188b000-7f11b1a8a000 ---p 00008000 08:05 1978507                    /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libPort_Std.so
7f11b1a8a000-7f11b1a8b000 rw-p 00007000 08:05 1978507                    /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libPort_Std.so
7f11b1a8b000-7f11b1c8d000 rwxp 00000000 08:05 1978502                    /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libisl_iostreams.soERROR:Simulator:772 - Signal SIGABRT received
Printing stacktrace...

[0] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x6d52b) [0x7f11af7bb52b]
[1] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x76d76) [0x7f11af7c4d76]
[2] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7a658) [0x7f11af7c8658]
[3] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_malloc+0x70) [0x7f11af7c9b90]
[4] /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE//lib/lin64/libstlport.so.5.1(operator new(unsigned long)+0x1d) [0x7f11b2b7909d]
[5] /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE//lib/lin64/libPortability.so(Port_MsgManData::createObject(char const*, char const*, int, char const*)+0x33) [0x7f11b286a043]
[6] /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE/bin/lin64/unwrapped/fuse() [0x5fe2ba]
[7] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0xf030) [0x7f11b0180030]
[8] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x1277fc) [0x7f11af8757fc]
[9] /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE//lib/lin64/libVrfc_Verific.so(Verific::Array::Remove(unsigned int, unsigned int)+0x3a) [0x7f11b3748906]
[10] /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE//lib/lin64/libVrfc_Verific.so(Verific::VhdlSubprogramId::ElaboratePragmaProcedure(Verific::Array const*, Verific::VhdlDataFlow*)+0x145f) [0x7f11b3a2e295]
[11] /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE//lib/lin64/libVrfc_Verific.so(Verific::VhdlSubprogramId::ElaborateSubprogram(Verific::Array*, Verific::VhdlConstraint*, Verific::VhdlDataFlow*, Verific::VhdlTreeNode*, Verific::VhdlIdDef*)+0xf3) [0x7f11b3a2e8b1]
[12] /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE//lib/lin64/libVrfc_Verific.so(Verific::VhdlIndexedName::Evaluate(Verific::VhdlConstraint*, Verific::VhdlDataFlow*, unsigned int)+0x12b) [0x7f11b3a4cc81]
[13] /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE//lib/lin64/libVrfc_Verific.so(Verific::VhdlProcedureCallStatement::Elaborate(Verific::VhdlDataFlow*, Verific::VhdlBlockConfiguration*)+0x3e) [0x7f11b3a85c7a]
[14] /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE//lib/lin64/libVrfc_Verific.so(Verific::VhdlWhileScheme::Elaborate(Verific::VhdlIdDef*, Verific::Array*, Verific::Array*, Verific::VhdlBlockConfiguration*, Verific::VhdlDataFlow*)+0x2b3) [0x7f11b3a38867]
[15] /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE//lib/lin64/libVrfc_Verific.so(Verific::VhdlLoopStatement::Elaborate(Verific::VhdlDataFlow*, Verific::VhdlBlockConfiguration*)+0xfe) [0x7f11b3a85da8]
[16] /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE//lib/lin64/libVrfc_Verific.so(Verific::VhdlIfStatement::ElaborateCore(Verific::VhdlDataFlow*)+0x24f) [0x7f11b3a88731]
[17] /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE//lib/lin64/libVrfc_Verific.so(Verific::VhdlIfStatement::Elaborate(Verific::VhdlDataFlow*, Verific::VhdlBlockConfiguration*)+0x52) [0x7f11b3a88e8a]
[18] /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE//lib/lin64/libVrfc_Verific.so(Verific::VhdlWhileScheme::Elaborate(Verific::VhdlIdDef*, Verific::Array*, Verific::Array*, Verific::VhdlBlockConfiguration*, Verific::VhdlDataFlow*)+0x2b3) [0x7f11b3a38867]
[19] /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE//lib/lin64/libVrfc_Verific.so(Verific::VhdlLoopStatement::Elaborate(Verific::VhdlDataFlow*, Verific::VhdlBlockConfiguration*)+0xfe) [0x7f11b3a85da8]
[20] /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE//lib/lin64/libVrfc_Verific.so(Verific::VhdlSubprogramBody::ElaborateSubprogram(Verific::Array const*, Verific::VhdlConstraint*, Verific::VhdlDataFlow*, Verific::VhdlTreeNode*, unsigned int, Verific::VhdlIdDef*)+0x1217) [0x7f11b3a10cdf]
[21] /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE//lib/lin64/libVrfc_Verific.so(Verific::VhdlSubprogramId::ElaborateSubprogram(Verific::Array*, Verific::VhdlConstraint*, Verific::VhdlDataFlow*, Verific::VhdlTreeNode*, Verific::VhdlIdDef*)+0x1aa) [0x7f11b3a2e968]
[22] /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE//lib/lin64/libVrfc_Verific.so(Verific::VhdlIndexedName::Evaluate(Verific::VhdlConstraint*, Verific::VhdlDataFlow*, unsigned int)+0x12b) [0x7f11b3a4cc81]
[23] /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE//lib/lin64/libVrfc_Verific.so(Verific::VhdlConstantDecl::Elaborate(Verific::VhdlDataFlow*)+0x8b) [0x7f11b3a0d7f1]
[24] /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE//lib/lin64/libVrfc_Verific.so(Verific::VhdlArchitectureBody::StaticElaborate(Verific::VhdlBlockConfiguration*)+0x9e) [0x7f11b3ac9c54]
[25] /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE//lib/lin64/libVrfc_Verific.so(Verific::VhdlEntityDecl::StaticElaborateInternal(char const*, Verific::Array*, Verific::Array*, Verific::VhdlBlockConfiguration*, Verific::VhdlIdDef*)+0x3ff) [0x7f11b3ac91d1]
[26] /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE//lib/lin64/libVrfc_Verific.so(Verific::VhdlEntityDecl::StaticElaborate(char const*, Verific::Array*, Verific::Array*, Verific::VhdlBlockConfiguration*, Verific::VhdlIdDef*)+0x157) [0x7f11b3ac7f35]
[27] /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE/bin/lin64/unwrapped/fuse(ISIMC::Fuse::elaborateDesign()+0x27a) [0x4550aa]
[28] /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE/bin/lin64/unwrapped/fuse(ISIMC::Fuse::run()+0x117) [0x46aaf7]
[29] /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE/bin/lin64/unwrapped/fuse(ISIMC::Fuse::main(int, char**)+0x59) [0x46bcb9]
[30] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd) [0x7f11af76cead]
[31] /opt/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE/bin/lin64/unwrapped/fuse(__gxx_personality_v0+0x209) [0x451c49]
```

Comment: Doesn't answer your actual question, but there's some PGM reading code here:https://github.com/martinjthompson/image_processing_examples/tree/master/hdl

Comment: Thanks but this looks like it's still under development, plus it looks pretty much like the library I'm using right now. Even if it would be usable, the library is not really my choice unfortunately. Thank you though!

Comment: The library as a whole is still under development (very slowly!) but the PGM read and write functionality works fine (and if you find a bug, I'll do my best to fix is pronto!)

Comment: I'll try it out if I'll have the possibility. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PGM is an ASCII-based format, which is as well because ISE Simulator has issues accessing binary files. (It can be done, but you have to jump through a few hoops, including a 9-byte header that Xilinx actually refuse to document)

The most likely cause is that you are attempting to return a fixed size 640x640x4 byte array on the stack, regardless of the actual image size. Whoever wrote that package needs their head examined.

But before going further along this line of reasoning, it is worth checking that a much smaller array on the stack will work. Find a small PGMfile (say, 16*16) and edit the package for a "max" slightly larger than the file (20*20 or 32*32 should be safe).

Assuming  that works, report back and we can work out a more appropriate solution : either a procedure with an OUT parameter (caller allocates it) or a function returning an access type (pointer) to the actual storage.

Alternatively : try GHDL as an alternative simulator. It has runtime options to control the stack size, which may bypass the problem.

EDIT following some experimentation:
(1) The "memory corruption" appears to arise on lines containing white space after the data. Deleting that in a text editor removes that issue (rewriting the line parser to eliminate that problem is probably a better answer...)

(2) After fixing that, the elaboration stage appears to hang.
A few asserts after the line `pgm.pixel(pi,pj) := number;` reveal that it IS actually running; crawling or slithering might be a better term. I haven't actually summed up the patience to let it run beyond line 100 so I can't say if the result is successful.

```
      pgm.pixel(pi,pj) := number;
      assert pi < 10 report "Pixel " & natural'image(pi) & " : " & natural'image(pj) severity note;
```

(etc)

EDIT following further digging:

Apparently ISIM treats elaboration differently from runtime computation; assuming that little or no actual work is done there, and its elaboration is neither to the same quality nor performance as the executable operating at simulation time.

So replacing the architecture with:

```
architecture behavioral of test_raw_tb is
    --constant infile : pgm_record_type := read_pgm_file(ifile);
begin   -- architecture

 process
 variable infile : pgm_record_type;
 begin
    infile := read_pgm_file(ifile);
     wait;
 end process;

end behavioral;
```

as one way of forcing the file parsing to be deferred until runtime; compilation succeeds, and simulation proceeds at a satisfactory speed until:

```
ERROR: Index 640 out of bound 0 to 639. 
ERROR: In process test_raw_tb.vhd:17
```

(this error does not occur with the whitespace fixed file, so there still seems to be a parser issue to address)

Comment: Thanks for your response Brian! 
I've tried to read pgm pictures: 256x256, 250x360, 400x320. All of them were loaded with max=640. Unfortunately none of them worked. 
I can't agree more that this library is some kind of cruel joke, nothing more. 
I've tried to use GHDL instead but that doesn't work on debian because of  usage of out-of-date packages in the project.

Comment: no, I suggest reducing the size catered for in the package (modding it) until it is in the kb region and MUST fit on stack. To something insanely small, even 4*4, and finding (or writing!) a tiny file to match.If THAT works we can move forward. GHDL ... updated ... for Debian IS available, I'll dig out the info tonight.

Comment: I've trimmed one of the pgm files to 4x4 and changed the package's max variable to 4 but the error just keeps occurring. I will be very grateful for an up-to-date GHDL, I couldn't find one.

Comment: I found something interesting in lubuntu 12.10 ghdl -r test_raw_tb --stack-max-size=32M
./test_raw_tb:error: open: cannot open text file pepper.ascii.pgm
/usr/lib/ghdl/bin/ghdl: compilation error, with no pgm file present.  With a small one (24 x 7) found on the web it ran.  The mcode version under OS X had trouble. [GHDL package for Debian Wheezy](http://jorisvr.nl/ghdl_debian.html) gcc-4.7.2.  (Brian is in the UK).

Comment: Thanks David, that was the link I couldn't remember when I was at work!

Comment: would that be "feep.pgm"? Running that in ISIM 14.3 I get no corruption, but the message: "WARNING: Simulation object /test_raw_tb/infile was not traceable in the design for the following reason:
The number of elements in the requested object is 409605, which exceeds the maximum traceable size of 65536 elements.  The maximum can be changed with the "isim set maxtraceablesize" Tcl " which is pointing to a size limitation somewhere...

Comment: A larger image : http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/pgma/lena.ascii.pgm (yes I'm a traditionalist where imaging examples are concerned!) does give the OP's error, during elaboration. This is pointing to an error in the function body, rather than when returning a value.

Comment: Many thanks for all your answers. Especially to you Brian for taking an effort to test this "library". I've tried to trim the spaces in the pgm files, but didn't notice the spaces in the ends of lines. The result is however really discouraging, ghdl is the natural next step. Thank you @DavidKoontz for the link and you Brian for bringing this up.

Comment: After moving the file read from elaboration stage to runtime I managed to run the whole thing. Again, many, many thanks!

Comment: One more thing VERY well worth doing : assuming you are a student, have your school open a Webcase against ISIM with both forms of arch to illustrate the difference. If you are not a student user, then do it yourself. Xilinx tech support are usually excellent and once convinced, will raise a change request to improve ISIM behaviour. (Probably around ISE16.1 if you hurry!)